# Updating field name on multiple components when one is updated

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components, angular-forms

I am creating a new component that consists of a list panel on the left and description panel to its right.

I am passing in a dataList to the list component and it populates the panel with the correct options. It emits a field's id number when a field is clicked to inform other components of the user action.

The right panel is a simple FormGroup that contains a field which gets its value from the data list using the field index emitted by the list component.

Is there a way by which I can update the FieldName on the right and have it update the field name in the list panel as the changes happen?

[image]

Comment: Yes, use a store or a store simelar structure. The right then triggeres an update on the item, while the left selects the whole list.

Comment: if those components have parent child relation then you can bind data from parent to child. If you have 2 or more independent components where value needs to be updated then you can use Subject or BehaviourSubject

Comment: I managed to resolve this by using a service to control the data model and calling the service to update the field name every time the 'Field Name' value was updated in the form.
It was easy to do this once I had subscribed to the field's values changes.

Comment: @BijayaRai can you post your solution in answer to know what exactly you did. Thank you